# Ajax-loaded HTML5-videos won't stop loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, html5-video

So I have a small project with a scrolldown-page where every new content area gets loaded with ajax because every content area has a background-video.

Everythings working fine but after loading approx. 6 pages on chrome the videos stop playing and on firefox everything starts lagging like crazy.

I am deleting every video from the DOM after they get out of focus to prevent this but it doesn't work.

Any tips?

Comment: Once you load a video it continues loading until it's finished. You can't stop that as it's part of the browser (as far as I know). 
Removing the video from the DOM also may not be a good idea, why not just pause it?

Comment: Damn that's bad. So even if I keep all the videos in the DOM, I can't tell the browser to first load the video that is playing at the moment?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Surely you'd want to load all videos and then play a video only if it's in view?
As soon as you put a video in the DOM the video will load, the only way to stop it is to put the `preload=false` attribute in the video element.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but I want to prioritise the loading of the video in view if others didn't finish loading if you know what i mean...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can prioritise loading of assets once they've been started. It's all handled by the browser core and, from what I can find, isn't available to manipulate via JS.